# Elementary question on standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics

While reviewing basic stat for the next semester I found that I do not know why the following important equality works:

$ Prob[X \leq x] = Prob [ \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \leq \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}] $

aka the “standardization.” I agree that if $X$ follows a normal distribution, then $ Z = (X - \mu) \ \sigma $ follows the standard normal distribution. But how would I “prove” the above equality? I may verify it mechanically using the CDF, but I’m pretty sure that’s not the way it’s done ...

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event $\{X\leq x\}$ is same as the event $\{\frac {X-\mu} {\sigma} \leq \frac {x-\mu} {\sigma}\}$ so these events have the same probability.

Comment: Yes, I agree! It's important to understand that $X \leq x$ and $\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \leq \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ are the same event, even though the expressions look different. So why are they same? Forget first everything about probability and just look at the expression
$$ \tag{1}
X \leq x
$$
This is a comparison between two numbers. Just like in normal algebra, you can subtract a constant, say $\mu$, from both sides to obtain
$$ \tag{2}
X - \mu \leq x - \mu
$$
This describes the same set of numbers as equation (1). Now you can divide both sides by a constant, say $\sigma$, ...

Comment: I see! This thread will be helpful for those who have the same question... thanks a lot, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Matti P. one can't completely forget about probability. E.g. if $\sigma < 0$ then the inequality would flip signs. Without a definition for $\sigma > 0$ the proof cannot be made